# Can I use existing #4 wire to supply a 15A outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I have a 2 part question.

1. Can you connect an existing 4 gauge wire to a 15 amp breaker? (The wire is already there, instead of me pulling everything out.)
2. Can I connect this 4 gauge wire to a 14/2 cable and run it underground to a GFCI outlet on the fence post?

Comment: You can try and after three hours of trying you will find just using the right size wire is faster.  Will find that 4 gauge will not fit into a 15 amp breaker well.

Comment: If fence post is a good distance away from breaker, might try 12 gauge, if using outlet for ~12 to 15 amp tools/motors.

Comment: The problem is the 4 guage wire is really hard to pull out from the conduit. I have tried. That was my first choice. Can I also merrete the wire at the breaker box to 14/2 that way it will fit 15 amp breaker?

Comment: That is what @isherwood suggested.  Run 14 or 12 gauge from breaker to junction box and connect 4g to it.  Need junction box for the splice to be code.

Comment: #4 awg won't  fit in a 20A breaker either, but it's probably worth the cost to use 12/2 and use a 20A breaker and give yourself a little more capacity.  (You can put a 15A duplex on a 20A breaker.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can put 4 awg wire on 15 amp breaker.

However with this size wire you will find nothing fits a #4 directly so you will need to get a splice.

splices that actually connect wires as large as 4 awg to wires as small as 14 awg  the part number is 971022 Morris.  I just happen to have a dozen on my desk.
you can find them for ~6$ ea . Depending on how far away the receptacle is this could be both a big savings and no voltage drop issues. Or just easier than pulling a new line but it is totally code compliant to do this.

There are other brands of these connectors / splices like Polaris I just happen to have the exact model you need on my desk (they are very handy).

Comment: Yes, you're *always* allowed to use larger wire than is required.  Only proviso is pigtailing terminals that won't take the fat wire, and increasing ground size in proportion with conductor size.